# How can I tell when an FTP is complete?

Tags: unix, shell-script

I have a cron job that processes files that my client's upload via FTP to my FreeBSD server. The cron job runs once an hour, and normally processing each file only takes a few seconds.

The cron job looks in the client's upload directory and moves any new files to a tmp directory. It then processes the file(s) and moves them into a final directory where they are then available to the public through a website.

The problem is, every once in awhile, the cron job runs just as a new file is being uploaded. It moves the half-uploaded file to the tmp directory, and tries to process it, and fails, of course.

Question: how can I determine if the uploaded file is complete? The only thing I can think of is checking the file size to see if it's changing, but that seems like a kludge. Is there some sort of flag or something that is set when the upload is complete?

Answer (score 4):

The safest way would be to search your ftp server logs for a "transfer completed" message (depends on the software).

If that is not possible only process files that have not been touched for some safe time, say 10 minutes. Use `find` to get a list of these files, e.g. for 10 minutes and your uploads in `$UPLOAD_DIR`

```
find $UPLOAD_DIR -amin +10
```

The `+` means "more than". See `man 1 find` for more information.

Comment: This may fail if the file is uploaded a second time just afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`fuser` may do the trick.  This lets you look at what processes are using a file.  Only move if no processes are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the cron job create an identifiable process name? If so, use ps with grep to see if the old process is still running.